# How to copy part of contents in one array to another?

Tags: python

I've got a list name `users`, and I want a second list named `account_no` to take only the first part of the contents of `users`.

```py
users = [
    'GB1520*Adam Johnson*07293105657',
    'ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883'
]

account_no = []

def find_accountno():
    for index in range(len(users)):
        # I want to take the first 6 characters of users[index]
        acc = users[index: 6]           
        account_no.append(acc)

print(users)
find_accountno()
print(account_no)
```

And this is the desired output:

```py
['GB1520', 'ZA5584']
```

But, instead, I'm getting this:

```py
[['GB1520*Adam Johnson*07293105657', 'ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883'], ['ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883']]
```

Comment: remove visual-studio-code and python-3.10 tags because they does not concern your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read a bit more about *slicing*; you'll see that it doesn't work the way you think it does.

You wrote:

```
acc = users[index: 6]
```

This is saying "take every element in `users` from index `index` to index `6` (*including* `index`, *not including* `6`), form a new list from them, and put them in `acc`".
For example:

```
l = [0,1,2]
b = l[0:2]
```

Would have the list `[0,1]` inside `b`.

If what you want is to grab the first six characters of `users[index]`, then you simply want `users[index][0:6]` (so `users[index]` is the string you wish to slice; then `[0:6]` employs slicing as described above to only grab the first 6 elements: 0 to 5). You can also drop the `0` (so `[:6]`).

**Some extras:**
Another two solutions, just to show you some fun alternatives (these use what's known as *list comprehension*):

```
def find_accountno_alt1():
    numbers = [user[:6] for user in users]
    account_no.extend(numbers)

def find_accountno_alt2():
    numbers = [user.split('*')[0] for user in users]
    account_no.extend(numbers)
```

Another point: I'd personally recommend simply passing the list (`account_no`) as a parameter to make the method neater and more self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to split the strings by "*" char and take only the first part (your account id)

```
account_no = [user.split("*")[0] for user in users]
```

EDIT:
full code for your task

```
users = ['GB1520*Adam Johnson*07293105657', 'ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883']
account_no = [user.split("*")[0] for user in users]

print(users)
print(account_no)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it says 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Ok sorry. This is quite strange. Try to execute the full code i append in the edit.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Im cycling on `users`, so `user` is a string in the `users` list. Is it wrong? I tried my code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you need to use acc=users[index][:6].

```
users = ['GB1520*Adam Johnson*07293105657', 'ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883']
account_no = []

def find_accountno():
    for index in range(len(users)):
        acc = users[index][:6]       #I want to take the first 6 characters of users[index]
        account_no.append(acc)

#print(users)
find_accountno()
print(account_no)
```

As for the multiple output, you are getting that because you are also printing the users list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative and more *Pythonic* way to write your code and get the results you want:

```py
def find_account_numbers(users):
    return [user[:6] for user in users]


users = [
    'GB1520*Adam Johnson*07293105657',
    'ZA5584*Dean Davids*07945671883'
]

account_numbers = find_account_numbers(users)

print(account_numbers)
```

The code snippet above will result in the following output:

```py
['GB1520', 'ZA5584']
```

Comment: Thank you, but why did you add a parameter to the function if the global and local variables are the same?

Comment: Because using global variables is not a good practice. Create the habit of passing parameters to your functions instead. That will yield in better code quality and fewer bugs.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate that and I'll definitely implement it, but shouldn't the local variable have a different name than the global one?

Comment: Not necessarily. They can have the same name without any problem. Python knows how to differentiate them. Also, let's say that in the future you decide to call your `users` list  `my_users`, for example, then you just need to adjust the function call to `find_account_numbers(my_users)`, without touching your original function.